# local variables loaded asynchronously with chained Q promises

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I have a doubt.. if I define variables before the `.then()` of a promise, I have them available inside the `.then()`, am I right? This is not true with callbacks, but it should using `q` promises.

To be sure of this, I am asking if the below code is correct, even in the case of multiple requests.

So the `arg2` of the second `.then()` is always the right one, and it's not the `arg2` of the last call to myapp().

```
function myapp()
{
    var arg1=1;
    var arg2=undefined;  // loaded async
    var arg3=undefined;  // loaded async

    call_promise(arg1)
          .then(function(data)
               {
                 arg2 = data;
               })
         .then(function()
              {
               arg3 = call_function(arg2);
               console.log(arg3);
              })
         .catch(function(err){});
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: It would work with non-promise callbacks just as well.

Comment: @Joe mmh maybe not but thank you, it's an interesting lecture. It's always good read some theory explained in that easy way

Comment: Just saying, [this is a horrible pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28250700/1048572) :-)

Comment: :P yes, I don't like it neither me, as suggested by @thefourtheye is much better, using return. thanks for the link with the explanation

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that will work. No matter how many times the function is called, there will new variables created in the function. And because of the closure property, the functions passed to `then` handlers, will still be able to access `arg2` and `arg3`.

But, the correct way to do this would be to, resolve the promises returned by `then` handlers, by returning the values, like this

```
function myapp() {
    var arg1 = 1;
    return call_promise(arg1)
        .then(function(data) {
            return data;
        }).then(function(arg2) {
            console.log(call_function(arg2));
        }).catch(function(err) {});
}
```

Comment: …and also the `.then(function(data) { return data; })` can be completely omitted.

Comment: @Bergi That's true, but that is kind of the point of the answer :D Returning value from the `then` handler